# Add a label at the end of plot line in Pine 4 Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

Please I'm a bit lost and I would appreciate if a skilled programmer could give me a hand:

I'm outputting many plot lines into a new indicator window and I would need to get them named. The idea would be to add a label at the end of each plot line, displaying the name of the security that each plotline represents (please see the example attached)

Any idea if this is possible with Pine4?

Please let me know

Thanks a lot!

````
study("Label?")

Symbol1 = input(title="Sym 1", type=input.symbol, defval="eurusd")
Symbol1close = security(Symbol1, resolution="", expression=close)

Symbol2 = input(title="Sym 2", type=input.symbol, defval="euraud")
Symbol2close = security(Symbol2, resolution="", expression=close)


//the idea would be to add the labels at the end of every single 
 of these 2 plots. On the labels should appear "eurusd and euraud"
plot(Symbol1close)
plot(Symbol2close)```

[labels on plotlines][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvPqS.jpg
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
//@version=4
study("Label?")

Symbol1 = input(title="Sym 1", type=input.symbol, defval="eurusd")
Symbol1close = security(Symbol1, resolution="", expression=close)

Symbol2 = input(title="Sym 2", type=input.symbol, defval="euraud")
Symbol2close = security(Symbol2, resolution="", expression=close)

// define label variable persisted between bars, see more about var modifier
// also you can use different label styles as label.style_label_lower_left
var l1 = label.new(bar_index, Symbol1close, Symbol1, style=label.style_label_lower_left)
var l2 = label.new(bar_index, Symbol2close, Symbol2)

// set up new xy params to labels on new bar
label.set_xy(l1, bar_index, Symbol1close)
label.set_xy(l2, bar_index, Symbol2close)

plot(Symbol1close)
plot(Symbol2close)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for :)